# 32-bit MinGW g++ can't find GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx

Tags: c++, windows, mingw32

I'm trying to build Clang using 32-bit MinGW on Windows 10, but I get a link error when building `llvm-tblgen.exe`:

> undefined reference to `_imp__GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx@12'

[GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformationex) is a Windows system proc.

But it seems that this is not Clang's fault; I only mentioned Clang to provide some motivation. It fails with the same error when I try to compile a C++ program that simply calls `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx` and exits:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 // as mandated in the Windows doc
#include <windows.h>

int main()
  {
  SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX Buffer[10] ;
  DWORD Len = sizeof (Buffer) ;
  GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx (RelationProcessorCore, Buffer, &Len) ;
  }
```

So it looks like a problem with my 32-bit MinGW. The command `g++ --version` outputs

> g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0

and the compile command is simply

> g++ test.cpp

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening, and how to fix it?

**Update** I updated MinGW and it seems to work now. So it looks like it was a problem with the MinGW libraries.

Comment: You need to add the MinGW import library that contains the Kernel32 functions to the linker options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MinGW 32 "undefined reference to \`ExitProcess@4'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682871/mingw-32-undefined-reference-to-exitprocess4)

Comment: @Mgetz: no, that was not the problem, See my update.